# SQL Server hierarchical query runs forever

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data

I have a table of records with source, destination columns and need all the relationships from source -> destination, so I got the following query for it

```
WITH RecordChildren ([Source], Destination, Guard)
AS 
(
    SELECT Source, Destination, CAST(Source AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',' AS Guard
    FROM Relationship
    WHERE Source = @RecordId AND RelationStatusId != 3

    UNION ALL

    SELECT rel.Source, rel.Destination, cte.Guard + CAST(rel.Source AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ','
    FROM Relationship rel
        INNER JOIN RecordChildren cte ON cte.Destination = rel.Source
    WHERE RelationStatusId != 3 AND cte.Guard NOT LIKE ('%' + CAST(rel.Source AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',%')
)
SELECT * FROM RecordChildren
```

The problem is that it's slow. In a table of 88991 rows, there is a record that has 3168 destinations and this query runs for 19 seconds till it completes. So maybe I have coded the query wrong or the table is designed wrongly?

Comment: The "problem" with queries like is that, as the name implies, they are recursive. Iteration isn't SQL Server's forté, however, using an rCTE is probably is strongest way of doing iteration as it's at least set-based iteration. If, however, you have such large hierarchies (you say one row has 3168 children) then things can be slow. I would, however, suggest posting the query plan, and the DDL and the table(s) used and their indexes, that will help us see if we can at least help the RDBMS. [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: Another thing to consider is using hierarchyid to amortize the cost of determining the relationships to mutation time so that select time is fast. If you want help with that, let me know and I can point you to previous answers I've made here.